# Ubuntu 12.04.1 dual boot - boots directly to Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, bootloader

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my computer as second OS. I shrank the Windows partition and gave Ubuntu about 40Gb of space. After this I created a live USB having Ubuntu 12.04.1, and booted using the USB stick, everything went like it should.

Having booted to the live Ubuntu I started the installation of Ubuntu. I allowed the installer to do its magic and install Ubuntu side by side with Windows 7. The installation finished without issues, cool.

However, when I restarted my computer, Windows 7 started loading immediately. This suggests that installation of Grub either failed, or it ended up in the wrong place.

Edit:
Here is the list of partitions on my hard drive

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848  1827614719   913703936    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1827616766  1909534719    40958977    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda4      1909534720  1953521663    21993472    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5      1827616768  1892798463    32590848   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1892800512  1909534719     8367104   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

How could I get the boot loader sorted out properly? I assume using the live USB and terminal, but what should I do with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from Ubuntu forums.

```
Boot to live Ubuntu

sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo umount /mnt

Reboot
```

Original thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499828&page=2