# How do I select in which OS my computer boots?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, login

I have Windows 7 on my PC and I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 in a separate partition but when the PC starts it goes straight to Windows 7.

How can I have the  option beforehand to chose which OS I want to log onto?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/189194/ubuntu-12-04-1-dual-boot-boots-directly-to-windows-7   --- although it would be nice to know if this laptop has UEFI or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had windows 7 and had the same issue.First try gently hitting F2 key RAPIDLY and REPEATEDLY as you turn on the system.Do not stop until the black bios info page shows.This will take you into your Bios setup

**WARNING:**  ***Do not*** change any setting you are not familiar with,look for the device boot up configuration page.Please be sure to read the settings explanation on the right side of the screen.This may or may not help depending on your setup.
The three other keys used on windows 7 for accessing screens before the full boot are F8, F9 or Delete. Always start from a turned off computer,not when restarting.Also you need to hit your key gently,yet very fast and repeatedly until it brings up a screen.

Usually F8 or Delete are assigned to bring your computer into safe mode.But they sometimes bring up boot screens,depends on the manufacturer.In short try each one individually until you find the key that corresponds to your needs.F2,F8,F9 then Delete.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, search for *easyBCD*, with this tool you can create a dual boot menu in the windows partition of your HDD,
unlike windows though it WILL detect your EXT partition ubuntu has been installed on and allow you to boot from that portion of the HDD.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNVIvVUwaf4 will give you a 2 min tutorial of EASY BCD, though the package is faily staright forward.

my PC dual boots between ubuntu 13.10 and vista SP2.
though I rarely use vista any more.